# Password protect directories when accessed from external IPs using Apache

Tags: apache, passwords, directory, local

Currently have password protection on my main and sub directories, however I'd like to make it only required when connecting from an outside IP address and password free when connecting from the local subnet.

Currently `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    <Location / >
       AuthType Digest
       AuthName "intranet"
       AuthDigestDomain /var/www/ http://10.1.2.2

       AuthDigestProvider file
       AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
       Require user user1
       SetEnv R_ENV "/var/www"
   </Location>

   <Location /dir1>
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "dir"
        AuthDigestDomain /var/www/dir1/ http://10.1.2.2/dir1

        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
        Require user user2
        SetEnv R_ENV "/var/www/dir1"
    </Location>

    <Location /dir2>
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "dir"
        AuthDigestDomain /var/www/ http://10.1.2.2/dir2

        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
        Require user user2
        SetEnv R_ENV "/var/www/dir2"
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've had a loot at [Apache's documentation on auth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#satisfy) but can't make sense of how I'd then implement the password protection in with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of searching brought this up http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-authentication-in-htaccess.html

Basically changed this:

```
<Location / >
   AuthType Digest
   AuthName "intranet"
   AuthDigestDomain /var/www/ http://10.1.2.2

   AuthDigestProvider file
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
   Require user user1
   SetEnv R_ENV "/var/www"
</Location>
```

to this:

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "intranet"
    AuthDigestDomain /var/www/ http://10.1.2.2

    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
    Require valid-user
    SetEnv R_ENV "/var/www"
    Allow from 10.1.2.0/24
    Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

Tested and it's all running smoothly.